# How to pass dictionary into another Azure Function within the same Function App

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App, which contains two functions - `function_1` and `function_2`. The structure is below:

```
Function App/
    function_1/
        __init__.py
        function.json
        sample.dat

    function_2/
        __init__.py
        function.json
        sample.dat
```

`function_2` processes some data, given an input. I need to be able to call `function_2` from `function_1` and pass in the data as an argument.

This is what `function_1` look like:

```
# function_1
import azure.functions as func
import function_2

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    function_2_data = function_2.main({"name": "Azure"})
```

It simply calls `function_2`.

`function_2` then looks like:

```
# function_2
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    name = req.params.get("name")

    if not v:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get("name")

    # Process and return some data using name
```

However, when I run `function_1` I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'params'`

Which occurs in `function_2` when trying to get the `params` attribute of `req`, as in `funtion_1` I pass in a dictionary. I then tried using the JSON library (specifically `dumps()`) to get a json string and pass it in as a parameter, but I get the same error (with str instead of dict).

So, how do I pass parameters into `function_2.main()` from `function_1`?

p.s. I have also tried just using POST, however I get a strange timeout issue and would prefer to just call the function directly.

p.p.s. I am running this all locally and don't even have anything on the cloud yet.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the HTTP request arrives, Azure Function Runtime converts the actual data read from HTTP (the protocol) and converts it to an `HttpRequest` object to call your Http Trigger function. In this case you have to DIY.

You're calling `function_2` with a `dict` instead of an `HttpRequest` object. Not sure how but I guess there is some implicit conversion from `dict` to `HttpRequest` which lets this code run in the first place.

Anyway, what you want to do is pass it a proper `HttpRequest` with `param` set. E.g.

```
# function_1
import azure.functions as func
import function_2

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  req2 = HttpRequest(method="", url="", params={"name": "Azure"}, body=bytes())
  function_2_data = function_2.main(req2)
```

---

Better approach is to refactor common code to common lib:

```
# common.py
import azure.functions as func

def handler_func(req: dict) -> func.HttpResponse:
    name = req.params.get("name")

    if not v:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get("name")

    # Process and return some data using name
```

```
# function_1
import azure.functions as func
from common import handler

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  return handler_func({"name": req.params.get("name")})
```

```
# function_2
import azure.functions as func
from common import handler

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  return handler_func({"name": req.params.get("name")})
```

Comment: [RTM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python#methods) and if confused you can post a question like you said.